# How can I make graphics to represent squares and cubes of a binomial or trinomial

Tags: graphics

How can I code a program to display, for example, $(a+b) ^ 3$ or $(a + b + c) ^ 3$ or $(a+b)^2$ or other variations of along the same lines.

A picture is worth more than 1000 words.

Here is a picture of $(a+b)^2$.

[image: example 1]

And here is one of $(a+b)^3$.

[image: example 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most elegant code I've written but it's a fair start I think.

```
draw[HoldPattern[(+a__)^2]] :=
  Module[{f1, n = Length[{a}]},
    f1[i_] := {i - 1, i + 1} i/2;
    f1[i_, j_] := (f1 /@ {i, j})\[Transpose];
    Graphics[{
      EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}],
      Array[{RandomColor[], Rectangle @@ f1[##]} &, {n, n}],
      Array[Text[(1 a)[[{##}]], Mean @ f1[##]] &, {n, n}],
      Array[Text[(1 a)[[#]], {-1/4, Mean @ f1[#]}] &, n],
      Array[Text[(1 a)[[#]], {Mean @ f1[#], -1/4}] &, n]
     }
    ]
  ]


draw[(a + b)^2]

draw[(a + b + c)^2]

draw[(a + b + c + d)^2]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I just used [`RandomColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomColor.html) for the colors as I was not sure the the actual colors you wanted; if you clarify that I'll try to implement it.
- This is only for the 2D case but similar methods could be applied to the cubic case as well.
- There is redundancy in this code but I felt that this form may be more readable than e.g. attempting to compress four [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) calls into two.